# Convert text to SVG/vector in a Word document (custom fonts)

Tags: pdf, fonts, microsoft-word-2013, svg, vector-graphics

I have a couple of custom fonts which I would like to use in a handout I am sending out. However, as a base font I use a custom font that other users will not have installed. Is it possible to embed this font one way or another in an Office Word document? I was thinking SVG or any other vector format (I don't want to use a rasterized image!)

Note that I also want the imported "image"/vector to be compatible with the pdf format so that I can export the Word document as PDF as well.

Comment: What are you planning to hand out? the Word file or a PDF? PDF is definitely preferable, and there you can (must) embed the font. No need for any vector objects…

Comment: @MaxWyss Well, I'll be writing the document in Word, but I'll save it as PDF and send it out as PDF. When you save a Word file as PDF, are the fonts automatically embeded?

Comment: When doing it right, yes, the fonts will be embedded and subsetted (only the characters actually used are embedded). The best export from Word to PDF (meaning quality and feature-rich) is done by the PDFMaker macro which gets installed when installing Adobe Acrobat. There you can configure the embedding, although AFAIK, the default setting is sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for SVG conversion, but if you want that it is doable with Inkscape.

Launch Word, create/open a document then go to

- File
- Options
- Save

and check `Embed fonts in document`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to embed fonts, you'll need Inkscape, which is free.

Write your text in Inkscape with whatever font you want, then with the text object selected (that means using the selection tool <kbd>F1</kbd>) go to **Path - Object to path**. Repeat this for all text objects. You can now double click the object and change each letter individually.

After you're done, go to **File - Document properties - Page** and click on **Resize page to content**.

Save the drawing as Enhanced metafile `emf` and make sure that the checkbox (**Convert text to paths**) from the dialog that appears is checked. Drag the `emf` in Word.

When exported to PDF, the graphics from `emf` is scalable and the font used in not embedded in PDF.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say that there is no need for SVG conversion. What is the other way?

Comment: @BramVanroy this answer is the other way: conversion to a vector format, but not SVG (Word doesn't support it). It's EMF format which is vector too.